# How to list locally-stored manifests

Tags: docker

When I do `docker manifest create ...` this manifest is stored locally and it is not pushed to the registry until I do `docker manifest push ...` but I'm not sure where it lives in the meantime, before it is pushed.

I know that I can remove the locally-stored manifest with `docker manifest rm ...` but my goal is to clean up any forgotten manifests that I created, so how can I **list** all the locally-stored manifests?

I expected `docker manifest ls` but no such command exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kind of surprised, that this is not documented anywhere. I had to investigate this myself by reading the source code of `docker-cli`:

- The `docker manifest create` command is implemented in `command/manifest/create_list.go`. It eventually calls [`manifestStore.Save`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/cde06fbf1da2dd3d9ebeeeec3f38c5aa0f666d2b/cli/command/manifest/create_list.go#L76).
- The `manifestStore` is obtained from `dockerCli.ManifestStore()`, which is implemented in [`command/cli.go`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/cde06fbf1da2dd3d9ebeeeec3f38c5aa0f666d2b/cli/command/cli.go#L189) like this:

  ```golang
  func (cli *DockerCli) ManifestStore() manifeststore.Store {
      // TODO: support override default location from config file
      return manifeststore.NewStore(filepath.Join(config.Dir(), "manifests"))
  }
  ```

So in short, you can list or remove all manifests by listing or removing the contents of `~/.docker/manifests` (or more precisely `${DOCKER_CONFIG}/manifests`).

This is not very elegant, but there's no better alternative at the moment AFAIK.